# Pushpins in ArcGIS map with Javascript

Tags: maps, arcgis

What would be the way to add a pushpin on a map so that when clicked, it will show a detail popup on top of the pushpin?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it in an ArcGIS Web application, or another web mapping framework?

Comment: ArcGIS Web App for Mobile browsers  (Compact)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use the ArcGIS JavaScript API and some of it's basic tools.  You'll want to use the graphics layer that is part of the map object and the default info window.  I put together a small sample on JSFiddle that show's the basics.

make sure to include the following in the head section of your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.6/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.6/"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SummerTop/jn5rw/1/

This will create a map object, then when the map is clicked, add a graphic to the map with some very basic attributes.  You should see a small black circle with no fill, just the black outline, if you click the new symbol, it will show a pop-up with the attribute we initially gave it.